# How do you set data validation on a range of cells with the Google Sheets API in PHP?

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I have the following code:

```
$requests = '{
  "requests": [
    {
      "setDataValidation": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": mySheetID,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 10,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 6
        },
        "rule": {
          "condition": {
            "type": "NUMBER_GREATER",
            "values": [
              {
                "userEnteredValue": "5"
              }
            ]
          },
          "inputMessage": "Value must be > 5",
          "strict": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}';

// $client is a confirmed, working authorized Google_Client object.
$serviceSheets      = new \Google_Service_Sheets($client);
// NOTE This is not the same object as in \App\GoogleSheets
$batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest;

$batchUpdateRequest->setRequests($requests);

$serviceSheets->spreadsheets->batchUpdate(
    // $id is correct.
    $id,
    $batchUpdateRequest
);
```

…and I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value at 'requests' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.sheets.v4.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.Request), \"{\n \"requests\": [\n {\n \"setDataValidation\": {\n \"range\": {\n \"sheetId\": \"1100288254\",\n \"startRowIndex\": 0,\n \"endRowIndex\": 10,\n \"startColumnIndex\": 0,\n \"endColumnIndex\": 6\n },\n \"rule\": {\n \"condition\": {\n \"type\": \"NUMBER_GREATER\",\n \"values\": [\n {\n \"userEnteredValue\": \"5\"\n }\n ]\n },\n \"inputMessage\": \"Value must be > 5\",\n \"strict\": true\n }\n }\n }\n ]\n}\"",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid value at 'requests' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.sheets.v4.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.Request), \"{\n \"requests\": [\n {\n \"setDataValidation\": {\n \"range\": {\n \"sheetId\": \"1100288254\",\n \"startRowIndex\": 0,\n \"endRowIndex\": 10,\n \"startColumnIndex\": 0,\n \"endColumnIndex\": 6\n },\n \"rule\": {\n \"condition\": {\n \"type\": \"NUMBER_GREATER\",\n \"values\": [\n {\n \"userEnteredValue\": \"5\"\n }\n ]\n },\n \"inputMessage\": \"Value must be > 5\",\n \"strict\": true\n }\n }\n }\n ]\n}\"",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I tried passing `$requests` as an array, but it says it needs JSON, so that's not the issue.

I've also tried passing the value of the `requests` key (array of objects) and the single `setDataValidation`request (object).

The request itself is copied from Google's [docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/data).

Answer (score 0):

That's invalid JSON:

```
     "sheetId": mySheetIdConfirmedCorrect,
                              ^---- unquoted string
```

Don't build your own JSON. Build a plain old regular PHP array structure, then `json_encode()` it.

JSON can also not contain "code", so if that `mySheet...` is actually a variable, that's again invalid JSON. You cannot pass anything other than data - expressions, code, etc... are all not valid in JSON.

Comment: It's actually a number, so it's not invalid. In my actual code, I do build an array and `json_encode` it, but I was falling back to the example in the docs.